# Gradle: excluding a jar from runtime dependencies

Tags: java, dependencies, gradle

I need to exclude a jar from runtime dependency via Gradle.

I am getting this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Conflicting persistence unit definitions for name 'ldb-jpa': file:/D:/EricFrancis/shared/build/libs/shared.jar, file:/D:/EricFrancis/shared/build/resources/main
```

I'm trying to exclude the jar.

How do I tell gradle to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Without more information (Gradle version, relevant parts of build script, etc.), it's hard to say. But since this isn't a Maven or Ivy dependency, I'd consider not adding it in the first place.

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately I cannot provide much more info. I am trying to tweak the dependencies for a specific task. I cannot remove the dependency on the shared jar. Is there a way to remove the dependency on the jar for one specific task?

Comment: Probably. It depends on the task and how it consumes the dependency. There is likely a cleaner solution, though.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that I did not understand how configurations worked.

I was able to exclude the jar via:

```
configurations {
    testRuntime {
       exclude module: 'share'          
    }
    testCompile {
       exclude module: 'share'
    }
}
```